# How do I download an image from Firebase Storage on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Storage to store images. I can't download these on the Android. I want to download all images of folder but for now I want to download just one, because I don't know how to download all images as a list yet.
I'm trying this

```
public static final String TAG = "AtividadesFragment";
    ImageView imageView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_atividades,container,false);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreateView()");
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference ref = storage.getReference().child("ImagensExercicios/abdominal_1.bmp");

        Glide.with(getActivity()).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(ref).into(imageView);
    }
```

Xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using the following code to get jpg images from Firebase storage.
To get bmp images, I think the difference will be in the parameter of File.createTempFile("Images","jpg") // or bmp.
I hope that it will work for you too.

```
private Bitmap my_image;
StorageReference ref = storage.getReference().child("ImagensExercicios/abdominal_1.bmp");
try {
      final File localFile = File.createTempFile("Images", "bmp");
      ref.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener< FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot >() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
              my_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
          }
      }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

One more note is that I am using this code inside an AsyncTask class to achieve asynchronous task behavior.

Comment: Can i use this Code in BottomSheetDialogFragment ? inside the function onViewCreated  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490176/how-to-display-firebase-storage-images-in-gridview

Comment: @Kingg I am noy sure how it will behave.

Comment: i am New to android can u pls Say Where we want to use this code inside the onViewCreated or in baseadapter

Comment: @Kingg I am not working with Android any more. I switched to Python and django. Sorry, I may not be able to help you. But there are many briliant devs here who are always helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to load a [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) into an ImageView with Glide:

```
StorageReference ref = storage.getReference().child("ImagensExercicios/abdominal_1.bmp");
Glide.with(getActivity()).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(ref).into(imageView);
```

That's not how StorageReference objects work.  A StorageReference is just a pointer to a file in your storage bucket.  If you want to download its content, you need to [fetch a download URL from it first](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()), wait for that task to complete asynchronously, then use that URL to load into the ImageView.