# I need help to download image from firebase using storage reference

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-glide

I can download an image in my image button using its URL if i store the URL as string beforehand, but when i try to load the same image in my image button using storage reference nothing happens. i did convert the storage reference to string and displayed it on a text button to make sure i have the right reference which i do. here the variables l1, lp, ll1, lp1 are LinearLayout and LayoutParams variable.

```
   `Button[] dhababtnarr = new Button[t];
    ll.addView(dhababtnarr[i], lp);
    ImageButton imagebutton = new ImageButton(this);
    strref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference stt=strref.child("image1.jpg");
    Glide.with(this)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(stt)
            .into(imagebutton);
    LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll1.addView(imagebutton, lp1);
    dhababtnarr[1].setText(stt.toString());`
```

Also i tried using .getDownloadUrl() to download the URL and use it in glide but the .addOnSuccessListener and also the .addOnFailureListener never gets executed. to check this i set a string to random "ss" value inside these listeners and set my button text as that string, and it does not display "ss" but rather is empty.

```
   `Button[] dhababtnarr = new Button[t];
    ll.addView(dhababtnarr[i], lp);
    ImageButton imagebutton = new ImageButton(this);
    strref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference stt=strref.child("image1.jpg");
     String URI="";
    stt.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
            URI="s";
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
            URI="s";
        }
    });
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(URI)
            .into(imagebutton);
      LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll1.addView(imagebutton, lp1);
    dhababtnarr[1].setText(URI);`
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/45704282) , you can create a bitmap and then set it on imageview :

```
private Bitmap my_image;
StorageReference ref = storage.getReference().child("image1.jpg");
try {
      final File localFile = File.createTempFile("Images", "bmp");
      ref.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener< FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot >() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
              my_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
             imagebutton.setImageBitmap(my_image)
          }
      }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**For Glide do this :**

In your build.gradle add :

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
}
```

Then in your activity try this :

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = ...;

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I tried that code and i get an "An unknown error occured, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response." as toast on my activity and no image loads. Also it would be a huge favor if u could help me use glide to download image in place of bitmap

Comment: I have added a solution for glide.

Comment: Sorry for not replying last couple days. Where do i add this code exactly, plus it says " cannot resolve symbol 'Factory' " in last line when i add this to my java class. and also "method does not override from its superclass" message displayed at @override. The helps are really appreciated.

Comment: Hey check this https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage ,try to follow the instructions in the readme file , do share if you can't follow it , i will create a working example for you

Comment: Add dependencies : implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

Comment: @TafelSmith Now check i have updated the answer , try this once !

Comment: I am sorry i for the late reply, but i couldn't get it to work, i am currently using download URLs for images, i ll be checking your solution if i get back to this problem again. Thanks for the little things i could get from your great help for now.